# Node.js : On SQL query that returns no record : TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js

**UPDATE : GOT IT WORKING** See bottom.

I've got this little script going to make a SQL query using node.js, using a variable supplied by a user in a discord channel (upperArgs). The idea is it prints found data in console, and prints "No record" in console if the query comes up null.

Works great if the query finds a record, but if it doesn't I still get

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'registered_owner' of undefined

I've tried a range of solutions like splitting the concat into two separate queries and more, but I can't seem to get this error to stop throwing.

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
 //Then ignores them if they are from another bot. 
if (message.author.bot) return;
  // Or if they don't have our specified prefix
if (message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return;
 // Or if they aren't in our specified channel
if (message.channel.id === (config.channelid)) {

 // Strips prefix, lowercases command, uppercases args to match db value.
const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
const upperArgs = args.map(arg => arg.toUpperCase());

var platequery = "SELECT CONCAT(firstname,' ', lastname) AS registered_owner FROM essentialmode.users where identifier = (Select owner FROM essentialmode.owned_vehicles where plate = '" + upperArgs + "')";

if (command === 'check') {

    var tag = await con.query(platequery, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err
      if (tag !== undefined)
      {
       var platedata = (result[0].registered_owner);
        console.log(platedata);
      }
      else console.log("Not found")
    });
  }
}
});
```

**UPDATE : GOT IT WORKING** using result.length

```js
if (command === 'check') {

    var tag = await con.query(platequery, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err
      if (result.length > 0) {
        if (result)
          console.log("Registerd to " + result[0].registered_owner)
      }
      else console.log('Stolen');
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check if result has a [0] element before trying to access its properties, and then check if registered_owner is in result[0].

Alternatively, you could use something like lodash and do `_.get(result,'[0].registered_owner',null)`

```
  if (typeof tag !== "undefined")
  {
   var platedata = result.length > 0 
     ? 'registered_owner' in result[0]
       ? (result[0].registered_owner) 
       : null
     : null ;
   console.log(platedata);
  }
```

Comment: I've been trying to check if registered_owner exists, as you may be able to see in the code above. I'm unsure how to check if the result has an element before calling it. The problem seems to occur at the var = platedata stage if the query is blank.

Totally unfamiliar with lodash. That would require another library right? Trying to keep this minimal.

Comment: I got it working with result.length, updated original post.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (command === 'check') {

    var tag = await con.query(platequery, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err
      if (result.length > 0) {
        if (result)
          console.log("Registerd to " + result[0].registered_owner)
      }
      else console.log('Stolen');
    });
  }
```